# Can't set root password for OrientDB using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, orientdb

I'm using the latest orientdb docker image in my docker-compose. I need to set the default root password but it's not working. My docker-compose.yml:

```
orientdb:
  image: orientdb
  ports:
    - "2434:2434"
    - "2480:2480"
    - "2424:2424"
  volumes:
    - "/mnt/sda1/dockerVolumes/orientdb:/opt/orientdb/databases"
  environment:
    - ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

I'm currently running:

```
$ export ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=anypw
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define password in `docker-compose`:

```
environment:
- ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=anypw
```

if you want to hide your password from `docker-compose` you can create `docker-compose`:

```
environment:
- ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

---

I have been able to reproduce your solution and it works:

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
version: '2'
services:
 orientdb:
  image: orientdb
  ports:
    - "2434:2434"
    - "2480:2480"
    - "2424:2424"
  environment:
    - ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
```

now:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network ... with the default driver
Creating test_orientdb_1
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                    NAMES
d1f0a4a81222        orientdb            "server.sh"         31 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds       0.0.0.0:2424->2424/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2434->2434/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2480->2480/tcp   test_orientdb_1
```

User: **root**
Pass: **test**

You probably tried to log in, but you have not created database.
[image]

Just create one and try to log in.

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. If I run the container manually without compose it does work.
Command: `docker run -d --name orientdb -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480 -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root orientdb`

Comment: @diugalde `-e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root`in `docker run` is eqal to `environment:
- ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root` in `docker-compose`. (if you dont believe check [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#/passing-environment-variables-through-to-containers) and further [Doc about inject of env variables](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/129092b7/docs/yml.md#variable-substitution)

Comment: Yeah I know that. If I put an echo and try to print the environment variable it works. The problem is that OrientDB is not reading that environment variable, so the passed password is not set.

Comment: That's weird. [OServer.java#L85](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/7850712aafb3cb7c61a5c2865710019df0a7e8c9/server/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/server/OServer.java#L85) in `start.sh` is using `String rootPassword = OSystemVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ROOT_PASSWORD_VAR);` so if `echo  $ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` **in container** works it should start successfully.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why it is not working. I have been trying to make it work for days. If I try to access orientdb using OrientStudio or the nodejs client using the provided password it just throws ` Wrong user/password`

Comment: @diugalde I tried to replicate problem and it worked. check my answer and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128303/discussion-between-diugalde-and-vladodemcak).

Answer (score 0):

You have to first run docker-compose down command.

Then you can run the docker-compose up command.

This will remove previous configuration and allow you to connect to the database.